# Command /usr/bin/lipo failed with exit code 1 error

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have finally finished my app and I was getting ready to upload when this sudden error hit me and I have no idea what to do. I have checked other posts saying to change the code signing identity and I have done this but no luck. I tried every single option in the identity and no change. If anyone knows what is going on I would really appreciate it since I would simply just like to submit my app.

Here is what else it says in the erorr log:

```
/usr/bin/lipo: /Users/teddy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/grocery_stores-dcyubhefhrcjhtcxbhldfpukdgdz/Build/Intermediates/grocery stores.build/Release-iphoneos/grocerystores.build/Objects-normal/armv7/grocery stores and /Users/teddy/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/grocery_stores-dcyubhefhrcjhtcxbhldfpukdgdz/Build/Intermediates/grocery stores.build/Release-iphoneos/grocery stores.build/Objects-normal/armv7/grocery stores have the same architectures (armv7) and can't be in the same fat output file

Command /usr/bin/lipo failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793392/how-do-i-compile-a-static-library-fat-for-armv6-armv7-and-i386

Comment: Hi @Teddy13 Are we talking about an xcode project that you built from the beginning or are you working on a project that you received from someone else and you are not familiar with it?

I'm asking because the error you received is related to building fat static libraries, that's something you can not do by accident. please explain a little bit more about the project you are trying to build

Comment: I resolved this by `wcarthage`.
Find solution at https://stackoverflow.com/a/63984866/7124289

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I solved this issue by changing the value of the Valid Architecture found in Project > Build Settings > Architectures from the default "armv6 armv7" to "armv7". Hope this helps.

Comment: Sure that's all fine and well but how does this affect your product? Will it not run on certain devices? There must be a side effect.

Answer (score 4):

It's hard to see what exactly is happening without the command you are running.  It looks to me like you are specifying the same input file twice, namely the arm7 version and lipo is telling you you can't add 2 arm7 versions of grocery stores to the universal file.  Can you please enter the entire lipo command you are running?  From the lipo man page:
        -create
                Take the input files (or file) and create one universal output file from them.
Do you possibly have the same file listed twice here?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your build target to a simulator build, clean and re-run.

Comment: This worked for me as well, but I didn't have to change the build target. Just a clean and build.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I used pods and oped projectFile instead of project workspace

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was building a project on simulator in a release scheme, changed it to debug and it worked.