# iOS test target build breaks, library not getting built for right architecture

Tags: objective-c, linker-errors

My project contains two targets, the main application and a separate target for testing. The main target builds no problem but the test target fails with the following linker warning:

```
"ld: warning: ignoring file .../libj2objc_main.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386)"
```

It seems like this is a common problem, and there are several posts that deal with solutions, from setting the "Build Active Architectures Only" flag to No (or is it Yes?) to using shell scripts to force Xcode to build a fat binary. (Using `lipo` I've confirmed that the compiled .a file only contains the x86_64 binary.) It's really bizarre that when I create a new test target and run the default XCTest suite everything builds fine, but if I attempt to add the Pods config file to the test target in Info -> Configurations and run the tests again everything blows up. This has never been a problem in other projects.

My question is why is this only failing for the test target? I'm using the same architecture in both the regular and test builds, so why is the `.a` only being a problem in the latter case?

Comment: check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803211/file-was-built-for-archive-which-is-not-the-architecture-being-linked-i386)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but unfortunately that's not the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out that the reason things weren't building was because (unbeknownst to me) my team was manually managing the header search paths. I'd encourage anyone working on a team to check the header search paths inside the primary target and see if they're all being added individually. If they are, you'll similarly need to add any test-specific headers manually in your test target.

Comment: hi, you need to add in all the header files of  libj2objc_main.a in the test case?