# Error building restkit for iOS Simulator

Tags: ios, restkit, linker-errors

I am having trouble building an iPhone project for iOS Simulator. Building for the device actually works.
The error is with the RestKit external library.
Here is what I get:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/omar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Zolkin-geukgbaipukxjhacrofvkapbkmme/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRestKit.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386): /Users/omar/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Zolkin-geukgbaipukxjhacrofvkapbkmme/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/libRestKit.a
Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AFJSONRequestOperation", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in GoogleMapsService.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RKAttributeMapping", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Distric.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RKObjectManager", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in BaseService.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RKObjectMapping", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in User.o
      objc-class-ref in City.o
      objc-class-ref in Distric.o
      objc-class-ref in ServerTimeInterval.o
      objc-class-ref in Address.o
      objc-class-ref in StoreDetails.o
      objc-class-ref in Store.o
      ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RKObjectRequestOperation", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in BaseService.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RKRelationshipMapping", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Address.o
      objc-class-ref in StoreDetails.o
      objc-class-ref in Store.o
      objc-class-ref in Consumer.o
      objc-class-ref in PaginatedStoreListResponse.o
      objc-class-ref in ExtractResponse.o
      objc-class-ref in CategoryData.o
      ...
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RKResponseDescriptor", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in BaseService.o
  "_RKlcl_configure_by_name", referenced from:
      -[AppDelegate application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:] in AppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

Thanks
Omar

Comment: How did you add RestKit to the project?

Answer (score 0):

This often means the .m file is not listed under Compile Sources in Build Phases of your target. Sometimes Xcode makes you add the .m file manually.

try this

TargetSettings -> Build Phases -> Compile Sources -> add your .m class ->Build and Run

The other thing to look out for are name conflicts. Make sure all your classes are uniquely named or you might get a similarly cryptic clang error

If none of that works check out this thread. It's possible, if you're running in a simulator, that it is trying to use the wrong processor architecture.

[file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (i386)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10803211/file-was-built-for-archive-which-is-not-the-architecture-being-linked-i386)