# Linker output while compiling custom libraries: File was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked

Tags: c++, build, architecture, linker, archive

I'm working with a simulation code which uses custom libraries and archives, at compilation time I get the following message:

**ld: warning: ignoring file ../nr/libnr.a, file was built for archive which is not the architecture being linked (x86_64): ../nr/libnr.a**

Can someone give me leads as to how this issue may come from?

Comment: Seems you are trying to use a file built for 32 bits in a 64 bit compilation environment or vice versa.

Comment: Yes, I thought so, but the cluster on which this program is usually executed is 64 and my MAC on which I'm trying to run it now is also 64 bits.

Comment: This could answer your question. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14720093/2000547