# issues trying to link project with libGoogleAnalitics.a for both armv6 and armv7

Tags: ios, google-analytics, armv7, armv6

I am trying to use Google Analytics iOS in my project, that supports iOS 4.0 onwards and looking at the Google Analytics resources [page](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/resources) I can see that version 1.5 they support architecture **armv6** and not **armv7**, and on 1.5.1 they added support to **armv7** but removed **armv6**.

So if my project supports both architecture, and I try to use 1.5.1, I get an error on the linker:

```
ld: file is universal (3 slices) but does not contain a(n) armv6 slice: libGoogleAnalytics.a for architecture armv6
```

If I remove armv6 from my project supported architecture list, it compiles fine, works on device and simulator, but then later on I will get an error when submitting to apple store, the validator says:

```
at least one of the following architectures must be present: armv6.
```

Is there any way to create a version of the lib with both armv6 and armv7?

Comment: libtool, see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793392/how-do-i-compile-a-static-library-fat-for-armv6-armv7-and-i386

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up changing the minimum version of the iOS (iOS Development Target) to 4.3 so it passed the validation and submission to apple store (4.2.5 and above will not need **armv6**).

However, after some research, I found out that the 1.5 version (there was no link to the tgz, but it was easy to guess given the latest 1.5.1: http://dl.google.com/gaformobileapps/GoogleAnalyticsiOS_1.5.tar.gz ) **did** contain support to **armv7**, as contrary stated by their change log.

By using [otool](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/otool.1.html), I could verify the supported architectures in the static library, and the project compiled and linked fine with this 1.5 version.